# How does pointer to Extra Segment works in 8086 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, masm

I am having a problem of understanding this part of the code:

```
CSEG_B SEGMENT AT FF100h
 ASSUME CS: CSEG_B, DS: DSEG  
...
   MOV WORD PTR ES:[8], OFFSET NMI_ISR   
   MOV WORD PTR ES:[10], SEG NMI_ISR
...
CSEG_B ENDS 

CSEG_C SEGMENT 'CODE'
 ASSUME CS: CSEG_C 

  NMI_ISR PROC FAR
  ...
  NMI_ISR ENDP 
CSEG_C ENDS
```

I know that the instructions `MOV WORD PTR ES:[8], OFFSET NMI_ISR` and `MOV WORD PTR ES:[10], SEG NMI_ISR` have anything to do with pointing to the function `NMI_ISR` in the other code segment, what I don't understand is why use extra segment for this? What is the purpose of the `ES:[8]` and `ES:[10]`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably `es` is loaded with the base value zero, to access the Interrupt Vector Table. The two words at offset 8 in the IVT (equal to linear address 00008h) are the offset and segment of the NMI (interrupt 2) handler.

Comment: Tnx for your help..

Comment: Yes, part of the code you snipped out and replaced with `...` was `MOV AX, DSEG`
  `MOV DS, AX`
  `MOV AX, 0`
  `MOV ES, AX` DS is set to DSEG amd ES is set to zero to access the interrupt vector table at the base of memory starting at 0x0000:0x0000

Comment: Is there another way of accessing or initialising the vector table?

Comment: Yes, it is, and much better: DOS software intterrupt 0x21 with AH=0x25:  http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2602.htm

Comment: @vitsoft :I believe that this code the OP is using is in E-PROM and part of a non IBM-PC compatible system using an 8086/8088. I don't think you can expect that DOS is going to be available at the point this code is run. There really is no other way of initializing that interrupt table except to update it directly.